# When using the POI library, the order of the charts is different than expected

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

I'm trying to modify only the data in a predefined chart format using the POI library.

The order is accurate up to three charts, but beyond that, the sequence in which they are retrieved is not correct. Is there a way to handle this?

Below is a sample code. Can you help?

```
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(templateFile));

    System.out.println(document.getCharts().get(0));
    System.out.println(document.getCharts().get(1))
    System.out.println(document.getCharts().get(2));
    System.out.println(document.getCharts().get(3));
```

Name: /word/charts/chart4.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml
Name: /word/charts/chart5.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml
Name: /word/charts/chart1.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml
Name: /word/charts/chart2.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnXIS.png)

Comment: The order is the order of the relations document->chart saved in `/word/_rels/document.xml.rels`. It is not reliable that the order corresponds to the order of appearance of the charts in the document body. Is it your goal to get the charts in order of appearance of the charts in the document body? Or what order do you expect?

Comment: thank you!

I want to retrieve the charts in the order they appear in the document body.

Answer (score 1):

The order of charts got via [XWPFDocument.getCharts](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getCharts--) is the order of the relations from document to chart saved in `/word/_rels/document.xml.rels`. It is not reliable that the order corresponds to the order of appearance of the charts in the document body. See https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_3/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.java?view=markup#l237.

To get charts in same order they appear in document body, they would must be body elements for Apache POI. Unfortunately they are not. There are much other elements of a Microsoft Word document which Apache POI not considers as body elements.

You could wait until Apache POI extends its code to consider all possible body elements. But that could be a long time.

Or you could know that all Office Open XML files (`*.docx`, `*.xlsx`, `*.pptx`, ...) are simply ZIP arcives containing XML files. So one can simply unzip a `*.docx` file and have a look into it. In `/word/document.xml` you find the XML for all body elements. There you will see that charts are in drawing elements contained in text run elements. The chart element links to the real chart in `/word/charts/` via a relation id. So if one knows how to handle XML using Java, then one can get the drawings in order of the text runs and then the charts out of the drawings via the relation ids.

Complete example:

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.SimpleValue;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordGetAllChartDrawingsFromRuns {

 private static List<CTDrawing> getAllDrawings(XWPFRun run) throws Exception {
  CTR ctR = run.getCTR();
  XmlCursor cursor = ctR.newCursor();
  cursor.selectPath("declare namespace w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' .//w:drawing");
  List<CTDrawing> drawings = new ArrayList<CTDrawing>();
  while (cursor.hasNextSelection()) {
   cursor.toNextSelection();
   XmlObject obj = cursor.getObject();
   CTDrawing drawing = CTDrawing.Factory.parse(obj.newInputStream());
   drawings.add(drawing);
  }
  return drawings;
 }

 private static XWPFChart getChartFromDrawing(XWPFDocument document, CTDrawing drawing) throws Exception {
  XWPFChart result = null;
  XmlCursor cursor = drawing.newCursor();
  cursor.selectPath("declare namespace c='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart' declare namespace r='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships' .//c:chart/@r:id");
  while (cursor.hasNextSelection()) {
   cursor.toNextSelection();
   XmlObject obj = cursor.getObject();
   String rId = ((SimpleValue)obj).getStringValue();
   result = (XWPFChart)document.getRelationById(rId);
  }
  return result;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordDocumentContainingCharts.docx"));

  for (IBodyElement bodyElement : document.getBodyElements()) {
   if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph) bodyElement;
    for(IRunElement runElement : paragraph.getIRuns()) {
     if (runElement instanceof XWPFRun) {
      XWPFRun run = (XWPFRun) runElement;
      List<CTDrawing> drawings = getAllDrawings(run);
      for (CTDrawing drawing : drawings) {
       XWPFChart chart = getChartFromDrawing(document, drawing);
       System.out.println(chart);
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

  document.close();
 }
}
```

Disclaimer: This code, as all of my code examples here, is a minimal example to show the principle. It should work but is far away to be usable in productive use cases simply by copy/paste. One needs understand the code to be able to implement it into productive usable code.